# Cannot Pass Argument to BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync (System.MissingMemberException)

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, exception, arguments, backgroundworker

I am creating a database job execution program that will allow users to automate data set retrieval from various API interfaces, and import them to our database.

Once all the jobs are loaded at application start, a background worker `engine_JobTrigger` starts a loop that repeatedly checks the date and time now and compares it to the `NextExecutionTime` of each job in the repository. If a trigger occurs, the background thread creates a new `BackgroundWorker` instance (required so that other jobs can be triggered to start), adds a handler to `DoWork` by `Job.ExecuteJob`, and begins the worker execution:

```
'Class definition for Job Executor Engine
Public Class engine_JobExecutorArgs
        Public SourceJob As Job = Nothing
        Public ExecutedAs As String = ""
        Public ExecuteStartTime As DateTime = Nothing
End Class
.............................................

engine_JobTrigger.DoWork \|/
.............................................
While Not engine.Cancel = True
   Dim jobsToStart As New List(Of Integer)
   If JobController.Jobs.Count > 0 Then
       For Each process As Job In JobController.Jobs
           If process.Schedule.isNowNextExecutionTime(process.LastExecutionTime) And Not process.isExecuting Then jobsToStart.Add(process.JobID)
       Next
   End If

   If jobsToStart.Count > 0 Then
       For Each JobID As Integer In jobsToStart
           'Argument passed to BackgroundWorker
           Dim newJobExecutorArgs As New engine_JobExecutorArgs() With {
               .SourceJob = JobController.GetJob(CType(JobID, Integer)),
               .ExecutedAs = Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(),
               .ExecuteStartTime = Now
           }
           Dim newJobExecutor As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()
           AddHandler newJobExecutor.DoWork, AddressOf newJobExecutorArgs.SourceJob.ExecuteJob
           AddHandler newJobExecutor.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf engine_JobExecutor_RunWorkerCompleted

           newJobExecutor.RunWorkerAsync(newJobExecutorArgs)
       Next
   Else
       Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
   End If

End While
```

All is well and good until I enter the `Job.ExecuteJob` function and try to declare the argument passed to the newly created `BackgroundWorker`:

```
Dim inputArgs As MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs = DirectCast(e.Argument(0), MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs)
```

```
System.MissingMemberException
  HResult=0x80131512
  Message=No default member found for type 'engine_JobExecutorArgs'.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.CallMethod(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags InvocationFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.InternalLateIndexGet(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateInvokeDefault(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean ReportErrors, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateIndexGet(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames)
   at Mastermind.Job.ExecuteJob(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in ...Mastermind\JobObject.vb:line 184
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? I would love to keep using a class object as an argument with my `BackgroundWorker`s, It would help me later when I finish and need to implement new features. How do I pass a custom class as an argument to 'RunWorkerAsync` in this scenario? Thank you for any advice in advance!

*EDIT:* Once the error occurs, I can successfully evaluate `e.Argument(0)` and view the values within the class via the IDE.

Comment: The call stack mentions late-binding so we should go no further with this issue.  You should go into the project properties and set `Option Strict On`, which disallows late-binding altogether, as it should be by default.  You should also set `Option Strict On` in the IDE options, so it will be on by default in all future projects. You should then fix ALL the errors that get flagged, which will be all the places you are relying on implicit conversions and late-binding. You need to make sure that you cast or convert EVERYTHING to the expected types. The places you can't are genuine code errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this about:

```
Dim inputArgs As MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs = DirectCast(e.Argument(0), MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs)
```

Why are you using `e.Argument(0)`?  `e.Argument` is just an `Object` reference and it refers to the object that you passed in.  The object you passed in is type `engine_JobExecutorArgs`:

```
Dim newJobExecutorArgs As New engine_JobExecutorArgs()

'...

newJobExecutor.RunWorkerAsync(newJobExecutorArgs)
```

Can that type be indexed, i.e. is it a list type?  No it isn't, so what would you expect indexing it to do?  `e.Argument` refers to an object of that type so you should be casting it as that type:

```
Dim inputArgs As MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs = DirectCast(e.Argument, MainWindow.engine_JobExecutorArgs)
```

There's no indexing to be done, which is what the error message is telling you.  You are trying to index a late-bound reference and it's telling you that there is no such member.  If you had `Option Strict On` then you would be told that indexing `e.Argument` is not allowed because `Object` is not an indexable type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was indeed my problem... How novice of me... I am new to using arguments. My reasoning for using `(0)` at the end was my assumption that in a scenario where multiple arguments are passed, you would be able to select from the array of objects passed as the argument. After research online following your post, I found that a `BackgroundWorker` can only pass one argument, so in the event you need to pass more than one value durring `RunWorkerAsync` you have to wrap them in a class. Thanks so much for your input @jmcilhinney

Comment: Still rather peculiar how in a Watch IDE expression I was able to evaluate `e.Argument(0)` with all the values passed, but in code it didn't. I didn't think to look at `e.Argument` because of this test, but today I've learned my lesson!

Comment: *"a scenario where multiple arguments are passed"*. There is no such scenario. The `RunWorkerAsync` method has only one parameter so you can only pass one argument. If you have multiple values to pass in then you have to package them in a single object and then pass that as a single argument. For instance, if you were to pass a single array containing multiple values then that is still a single argument. You could index the array once you get it back from `e.Argument` but you should have to cast it as an array first, because you should have `Option Strict On`.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, truly, but your negativity is just toxic... "There is no such scenario" yeah, well, if you read my question, I have one right here.... Anyway, thanks for the advice, huge time savor (but wow, you need to lighten up)

Comment: Also, I should have been more specific, I'm new to using arguments with a BackgroundWorker, not as a whole.

Comment: *"I have one right here"*. No, you don't. In the code you posted, you are creating a single `engine_JobExecutorArgs` object and passing that as an argument. The fact that that object has three properties isn't relevant to this particular point. `RunWorkerAsync` only has one parameter so it can only accept a single argument. The fact that you think you're passing multiple arguments is probably why you think that indexing `e.Argument` is OK, which is why I am pushing this point. The misconception you are clinging to is probably the reason for the issue in the first place.

Comment: *"your negativity is just toxic"*. I'm sure exactly what negativity you're talking about. I just stated a fact. There is no such scenario and your insistence that this is one doesn't change that. My agreeing with you won't change it either and it won't help you avoid similar mistakes in the future. Maybe you think I should have softened the blow a bit. I didn't call you an idiot for thinking the wrong thing or the like. I simply pointed out that you were wrong. Why is that negative?